# Mysql Sub Databases?? What are they called

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

[image]

I am looking at phpmyadmin and I see somethign that looks like sub-databases in mysql.  What are these called!?  Of course I have tried to search google but I have not gotten too far because I don't know even remotely what these things are referred to as? schemas? sub-databases?
any help would be appreciated. ty.

Comment: There is no such thing as sub-database. Also, word of advice: don't use PHPMyAdmin, it's one of the worst MySQL management tools out there, not to say one of the most insecure ones.

Comment: @N.B. I don't use it for personal projects unfortunately at work every mysql server has it installed.

Comment: Yeah, these are just ordinary databases - phpMyAdmin is just grouping them together. As an aside, I quite like phpMyAdmin - whether something is 'best' or 'worst' is mostly subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a name for these -> you get them in PHPMyAdmin if you name something with an underscore (like "maindb" and "maindb_test" ), but for MySQL itself there is no difference. It's just how PHPMyAdmin tries to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

You can organise your tables in PhpMyAdmin, by using a double underscore after the first (grouping) part of the name, e.g.:

projecta__table1

projecta__table2

projectb__table1

projectb__table2

These tables will be grouped according to project in the PhpMyAdmin interface.

Answer (score 2):

They are databases. phpMyAdmin is just listing them in a funny way (categorizing on the string before the first underscore (_)).